# How do I keep 8P8C jack plugged in without using clip?

Tags: networking, cable

I've been having bad luck with standard network 8P8C connectors. I've broken clips on almost all of my network cables and I even managed to break the part of receptacle on my modem which mates with the clip.

I know that the best way to solve the problem is to replace the receptacle and replace damaged connectors, but in the meantime I'm looking for ways to keep the jack inside the receptacle without relying on the clip.

Just to clarify the problem a bit: I do not want to glue the connector to the receptacle, so I'm looking for a non-permanent solution.

Comment: "*but in the meantime I'm looking for ways to keep the jack inside the receptacle without relying on the clip*" - that's what SHE said!

Comment: @taspeotis  I'm sorry, I don't understand the context of your comment.

Comment: I suspect "That's what she said" may be an English colloquialism you're unfamiliar with.  http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=that%27s%20what%20she%20said

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I once saw an elastic band looped around the cable and then around the kit - works for small devices such as modems, desktop switches etc.

There you go - hot off the press from the L3K labs:

[image]

**Alternatives**

Elegant:

- Start with two turns of clear adhesive tape around the cable just outside the connector.
- Cut the tape so that there is enough length to stick to the body of the equipment.
- Pinch the tape together into a 'cable', leaving enough end unpinched (about 10-15mm) for sticking to the equipment
- Stick the unpinched bit to the equipment to anchor the connector in place.
- Repeat the exercise so that you create another anchor to the body of the equipment on the opposite side to the first one.

Effective:

- A blob of hot melt glue, but make sure you don't melt the plastic case of the kit.

Expedient (unless the kit gets warm):

- [Blu-tack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-Tack) is your friend!

Comment: What's Bluetak?

Comment: wow, i thought bluetak was a world-wide term.

Comment: I've only ever heard it called 'Sticky Tack'.

Comment: I finally managed to obtain rubber bands of pictured size and they work great!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to bodge up a strain-relief or a redirect for the cables (letters 'o' in the diagram).  Can you maybe use dowels, bits of coat-hanger wire, a key-ring tied to something, some existing part of the shelf the modem is on, duct-tape the cables to the top of the modem or to some part of the surrounding structure....  You did say this is temporary, right? :-)

[image]